# Using TableAdapter to insert rows into a dataset does not do anything

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert, tableadapter, mdf

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550437/insert-method-of-tableadapter-not-working), but reading the (accepted) answer didn't give me much insight, so I'm hoping to state it more clearly and get a clearer response back.

I'm attempting to insert a data row into a table. I'm using `TableAdapter`'s custom "insert nonQuery" that I wrote (it works, I tested) to accept some parameters. I'm fairly new to this business of communication with a database via .NET and what I'm doing is probably wrong by design. My questions are *why is it wrong* and *what's the right way to do it*? Both are equally important, IMO.

Here's some sample VB code I wrote:

```
Dim arraysTableAdapter As New UnitTestsDataSetTableAdapters.ArraysTableAdapter

Try
    arraysTableAdapter.InsertArray("Test Array", 2, 1, 2, "Test user")
Catch ex As SqlException
    MsgBox("Error occured when trying to add new array." _
          & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
          & ex.Message)
End Try
```

...and that's pretty much it. There is no exception raised, my table does not get a new row inserted. Everything is just the way it was before I called the `InsertArray` method. When I test my query in the QueryBuilder with the same parameters, a new row gets added to the database.

Now, I do understand some of the reasons this would not work. I understand that I need to create and select a row in my `DataSet` (no idea how to do it) in order to tell the `TableAdapter` what it's adding the data to. Or at least I got that impression from reading the vast abyss of forums.

I would really like to use `TableAdapter` at some point, because it knows that `.InsertArray` exists and it knows which parameters it likes. I could try and do it using

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    con.ConnectionString = connString
    con.Open()

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ...... all that jazz"
```

but it's not nearly clean enough for how clean I like my code to be. So, is there any way to do what I'm trying to do the way I'm doing it? In other words, how do I use the neat structure of a `TableAdapter` to communicate to my `DataSet` and put a new row in it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two things that were wrong:

1. (minor issue) I did not have a `DataTable` filled from the `TableAdapter` (see code below)
2. (major, sneaky issue) My method worked from the very beginning. There is *nothing* extra to be added except for the line above. However, the `ConnectionString` of `arraysTableAdapter` was pointing my program (automatically, by default) to a wrong location. Once I manually set the `ConnectionString`, it worked perfectly.

Here's my complete code:

```
    Dim connString As String = "Some correct connection string"
    Dim arraysDataTable As New SpeakerTestsDataSet.ArraysDataTable

    Dim arraysTableAdapter As New UnitTestsDataSetTableAdapters.ArraysTableAdapter

    'Set the correct connection string'
    arraysTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = conn 

    'Fill table from the adapter'
    arraysTableAdapter.Fill(arraysDataTable)

    Try
        arraysTableAdapter.Insert("Test", 2, 1, 2, Now, Now, "Me")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error occured when trying to add new array." _
              & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
              & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: You have no idea how your #2 description helped me out!  This is the only reference IN_THE_ENTIRE_INTERNET that suggested this could be a problem.  I was trying to verify my inserts were working by checking the datasource, and not the database in the /bin/Debug/ folder!  #hateVb

Comment: @Wes Awesome! Glad it helped someone out.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer in the question you linked to is correct, but sometimes saying it in different words helps:

A TableAdapter is used to communicate between a DataTable (there can be one or more DataTables in a DataSet) and a database.  It can pull data from a database and add it to a DataTable and it can send data from a DataTable to the database.  It's purpose is to create and execute the SQL code required to make this communication work.

You are trying to use the TableAdapter to directly add data to your DataTable.  This will not work.  Instead, you should use the methods that come with the DataTable to add a new row to the DataTable and then (if necessary) use your TableAdapter to send that row to a database.

For instance, with a Dataset called DataSet1 that contains a DataTable called DataTable1 that has three text columns you can add a record like this:

```
    Dim d As New DataSet1
    d.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row("value1", "value2", "value3")
```

That AddDataTable1Row method is automatically created for you, and I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: That does make sense; however, as you can see I am trying to use my own SQL nonQuery `.InsertArray` that takes care of inserting a new row into the table. In the process, it calculated certain things, stores timestamps, generates a unique ID and does many more things. It's not as trivial as simply inserting data into containers. What I'm trying to find out is whether I could use that same method. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Does calling `.InsertArray` add data to your database?  If so, then you could change the SQL that is called by `.InsertArray` to return a row that matches the schema of your DataTable.  You can then change the ExecuteMode back to Reader and it will fill your database and DataTable at the same time.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was something completely different (settings, basically). I'm posting my solution right now. Thanks for the effort though.