# Insert from TableAdapter

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have to insert from winform in database access,

```
INSERT INTO Artikulli
             (Artikulli, Sasia, Cmimi, BID)
VALUES        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

What I need to write in ( ?,?,?,?) ,
I am connecting with db Access ?

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to write any thing replacing ?.

You will have to pass parameters.

Eg.

```
cmd=new SqlCommand("insert into.....");

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Artikulli", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Artikulli;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Okej @Freelancer .. but what to write in AddButton to call tham.. 
Ex.   this.artikulliTableAdapter.(...)

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search gave this: [How to: Insert New Records into a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-5). MSDN descripbes how tableadapters works in common. There is a simple example too!

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring with Insert values using `TableAdapter`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384028/1129189) Phonon answer to handle this. Best of luck!