# Updating the database from dataset after altering it in c#

Tags: c#, dataset

I trying to insert values to the dataset and i want the corresponding chages to be reflected in the database . I'm using this code:

```
_MyDatabase_1DataSet obj = new _MyDatabase_1DataSet();
MyDatabase_1DataSetTableAdapters.t1TableAdapter mytable = new testingconnection._MyDatabase_1DataSetTableAdapters.t1TableAdapter(); 
     mytable.Fill(obj.t1);
     obj.t1.Rows.Add("new value");
     mytable.Update(obj);
```

But the change is  getting reflected in the dataset and not in the database. When i use another instance of the dataset I am able to get the new row but the updation is not reflected in the database(.sdf)

Comment: No. It didn't throw any error.

Comment: can you please try  `mytable.Update(obj.t1);`

Comment: I tried all the overloads for Update but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try

```
 _MyDatabase_1DataSet obj = new _MyDatabase_1DataSet();
 MyDatabase_1DataSetTableAdapters.t1TableAdapter mytable = new testingconnection._MyDatabase_1DataSetTableAdapters.t1TableAdapter(); 
 mytable.Fill(obj.t1);
 DataRow dr=obj.t1.NewRow();
 dr[0]="new value";
 obj.t1.Rows.Add(dr);
 mytable.Update(obj.t1);
```

also try this

[Insert method of TableAdapter not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550437/insert-method-of-tableadapter-not-working)